# AJAX returning 404 Not Found

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

I am trying to get data from my database using ajax call but it returns this error:

[image]

This is my AJAX call

```
$.ajax({ 
   url : '<?php echo base_url('Create_controller/getCategory'); ?>',
   dataType : 'json',
   success: function(data) {
       $(data).each(function(){
            $('#create_category').append($('<option>', {
                 value: this.id,
                 text: this.category,
             }));
        })
   },
   error: function(errorw) {
       alert("error");
    }
});
```

This is my Create_controller:

```
public function getCategory(){
    $categories = $this->create_model->getCategory();
    echo json_encode($categories);
}
```

This is my Create_model:

```
function getCategory(){
    $this->db->select('id, category');
    $this->db->from('category');
    $this->db->where('status', 1);
    $this->db->order_by('category', 'asc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

I know that my controller and model works because I have tried using `print_r($this->create_model->getCategory());` before loading the view.

I have been searching for 3 hours now but none of them solves my problem.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this problem is that I forgot to add my `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check that you are posting data in a post method or get method. Try this function to call Ajax:

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "yourURl",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json"
});
```

Comment: Okay sir but where will I put this? Sorry I'm quite new to AJAX. BTW, I have edited my question. I forgot to put my AJAX call. Now it's there.

Comment: After datatype:json put type:post nd let me know

Comment: I'm getting a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` on the line where I added the ` var request = $.ajax({ url: "yourURl", type: "POST", dataType: "json" });`

Comment: Can I get back to you sir I'll just go to school. Thanks.

Comment: ok.you can also change the method name in controller and try it

Answer (score 0):

Your controller doesn't exist where you expect it. Right-click on to the URL in the error message and try "open in new tab" if you're in Chrome. This has nothing to do with Ajax. It's related to your MVC setup and routing.

Comment: How can this be possible if in my index function in that create controller, I can get values using `print_r($this->create_model->getCategory());`

Comment: You are saying that you're calling the exact same URL as per the error msg in a browser window and you get output other than 404? But from within Ajax it's 404?

Comment: I can't say if it is the same URL but if my Create_controller doesn't exist. How can I view the page because my Create_controller is my main_controller where I load the home page.

Comment: why can't you say if it's the same URL or not???? Just right-click it from the console and 'open in new tab' - then you can compare what's in your location bar with what's in your code. And you'll probably get a 404.

Comment: This the URL when I right click the error from the console `http://localhost/ppmp/Create_controller/getCategory`

Comment: so then what does the browser window say? 404 or your expected array? Do you understand what we're trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

This is temporary but replace

`'<?php echo base_url('Create_controller/getCategory'); ?>'`

with

`"<?php echo base_url('Create_controller/getCategory'); ?>"`

and say if it works...